# Closing a home loan and credit card use

Tags: united-states, credit-card, home-loan

I'll be closing on a home loan in the next month. I'm aware of the risks of running up credit during this period. Right now I have a very low credit utilization ratio (~5% or less). I'd like to make a purchase costing about $1,500 soon. I'd like to put it on a credit card (to earn some points), and pay the CC balance immediately. Is there a risk in doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pay it off as soon as it hits the credit card. If the lender notices it just explain it. As long as you still have the money for the down payment you should be good.

It is not unusual to have some items hit the credit card near closing. Deposits for moving companies, or the rental of a storage unit are not an unusual part of the moving process. You also may have some expenses for closing out the old house.

If the large expense is not related to the moving they may ask for more explanation, but it shouldn't be a big deal. Of course if it is a luxury item such as a new car they may get concerned.

Answer (score 3):

I was in this exact situation about a month or two ago. I simply sent my lender an e-mail asking if it was alright to put a large purchase(~$1500) on my credit card and if it would have any impact on my loan. They said it would be completely fine and I had no issues with my loan. Each lender is different and I would double check with them before purchasing just in case.